# logrotate permission denied

Tags: linux, debian, logrotate

**Why am I getting permission denied on renaming my log file when running** `logrotate`? The owner of my log file shown below is `rajohns` which is the same user that is logged in running the `logrotate` command shown below.

**$ cat /etc/logrotate.d/judgecard-api-0.0.1**

```
/var/log/judgecard-api-0.0.1.log {
    su rajohns rajohns
    weekly
    rotate 4
    create 0777 rajohns rajohns
    missingok
    notifempty
    postrotate
        systemctl restart judgecard-api-0.0.1.service > /dev/null
    endscript
}
```

**$ ls -l /var/log/judgecard-api-0.0.1.log**

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 rajohns rajohns 10578 Feb 12 23:01 /var/log/judgecard-api-0.0.1.log
```

**$ sudo logrotate -vf -s ~/logrotate_test_status_file judgecard-api-0.0.1**

```
reading config file judgecard-api-0.0.1

Handling 1 logs

rotating pattern: /var/log/judgecard-api-0.0.1.log  forced from command line (4 rotations)
empty log files are not rotated, old logs are removed
switching euid to 1000 and egid to 1000
considering log /var/log/judgecard-api-0.0.1.log
  log needs rotating
rotating log /var/log/judgecard-api-0.0.1.log, log->rotateCount is 4
dateext suffix '-20180212'
glob pattern '-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
renaming /var/log/judgecard-api-0.0.1.log.4 to /var/log/judgecard-api-0.0.1.log.5 (rotatecount 4, logstart 1, i 4), 
old log /var/log/judgecard-api-0.0.1.log.4 does not exist
renaming /var/log/judgecard-api-0.0.1.log.3 to /var/log/judgecard-api-0.0.1.log.4 (rotatecount 4, logstart 1, i 3), 
old log /var/log/judgecard-api-0.0.1.log.3 does not exist
renaming /var/log/judgecard-api-0.0.1.log.2 to /var/log/judgecard-api-0.0.1.log.3 (rotatecount 4, logstart 1, i 2), 
old log /var/log/judgecard-api-0.0.1.log.2 does not exist
renaming /var/log/judgecard-api-0.0.1.log.1 to /var/log/judgecard-api-0.0.1.log.2 (rotatecount 4, logstart 1, i 1), 
old log /var/log/judgecard-api-0.0.1.log.1 does not exist
renaming /var/log/judgecard-api-0.0.1.log.0 to /var/log/judgecard-api-0.0.1.log.1 (rotatecount 4, logstart 1, i 0), 
old log /var/log/judgecard-api-0.0.1.log.0 does not exist
log /var/log/judgecard-api-0.0.1.log.5 doesn't exist -- won't try to dispose of it
renaming /var/log/judgecard-api-0.0.1.log to /var/log/judgecard-api-0.0.1.log.1
error: failed to rename /var/log/judgecard-api-0.0.1.log to /var/log/judgecard-api-0.0.1.log.1: Permission denied
switching euid to 0 and egid to 0
```

Comment: Do you have write permission in `/var/log` with user `rajohns`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously the /var/log rotate fails, as the directory normally belongs to root:adm.

You can have a look at Apache and others to see how they do it.

The usual way of doing it is creating a subdirectory under /var/log and making another user the owner of it:

```
 sudo mkdir /var/log/judgecards
 chown rajohns /var/log/judgecards
```

Then move the old logs and create new logs of your app here.

Comment: This worked. I'm still a little confused though. I was able to manually create/rename files in /var/log with `rajohns`, so why couldn't `logrotate` do it when run from `rajohns`?

Comment: root can create a file and give it to `rajohns` under /var/log ; then `rajohns` will be able to use it. However, unless you messed around with /var/log default permissions, rajohns cannot create new files there.